# Removing an item from a list - C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have rather a complex datastructure. The simple version looks like this:

```
public class Field
{

  List<FieldRow> fieldRow;

  //I want to write a delete that iterates and deletes given the key 
  //(Use Linq?)
  public void DeleteByKey(int key)
  {
    //Do Remove
  }
}

public class FieldRow
{
  public int key;
}
```

Any help in implementing Delete is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Field
{
  List<FieldRow> fieldRow;

  public void DeleteByKey(int key)
  {
    fieldRow.RemoveAll(row => key == row.key);
  }
}

public class FieldRow
{
  public int key;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>().RemoveAll()` will do what you want.

You give it a Predicate delegate type, that is executed for each item, like a where clause:

```
fieldRow.RemoveAll(item => item.Key == key);
```

However, you might want to consider storing the data in a `Dictionary<int, FieldRow>`.  That way you can access the dictionary/map directly by key.  This would improve performance.

Comment: You really don't want to call it on a *new* list though... fieldRow.RemoveAll is what you mean, I think :)

Comment: Oops, well spotted.  That's what I get for switching to VS to get syntax colouring and intellisense!

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index of the field you need to remove and use the RemoveAt method on List.

<strike>I will add an example in a minute.</strike>
Nevermind, the suggestion to use RemoveAll with a predicate seems to be a better option :-)